Want to run command mvn test with a specific testng.xml file
This is my plugin in POM.xml file:
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.20</version>
            <configuration>
                <argLine>
                    -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.9.22/aspectjweaver-1.9.22.jar"
                </argLine>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <!--suppress UnresolvedMavenProperty -->
                    <suiteXmlFile>${suiteFile}</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

This lets me to run tests from a specific testng.xml file with terminal command:
mvn test -DsuiteFile=${absolute_path_of_testng.xml}
I want it to be so that instead of giving absolute path, only to give testng file name and run the tests correspondingly:
mvn test -DsuiteFile=${name_of_testmg.file}
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.20</version>
            <configuration>
                <argLine>
                    -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.9.22/aspectjweaver-1.9.22.jar"
                </argLine>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <!--suppress UnresolvedMavenProperty -->
                    <suiteXmlFile>${basedir}/${suiteFile}</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

I added ${basedir} to my suiteXmlFiles tag so that it will give my projects base directory dinamically but I think I am doing it wrong
The error message I'm getting:
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ----------------------< org.example:POMStructure >----------------------
[INFO] Building POMStructure 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO]   from pom.xml
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.089 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-06-26T16:38:51+04:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase ".xml". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: pre
-clean, clean, post-clean, validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/LifecyclePhaseNotFoundException


is there a specific reason why you use such ancient version of the plugin? 2017? Better use most recent version of plugins: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/

Your configuration looks fine. What error are you seeing? Can you please edit your question and share the error details? Also shouldn't that variable be ${project.basedir} as explained in https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Available_Variables

@KrishnanMahadevan I edited the question, thank you. Basically, I echo -ed the directory it is giving me and it shows the correct one, also tried like that but still did not succeed in successfully running the testing file..

@khmarbaise Basically because I do not know how to control the plugin version, thank you for noticing, if you assist I'll be grateful.

@KrishnanMahadevan found the issue, the terminal command should be executed in a different way. Instead of mvn test -DsuiteFile=testng.xml it should have been mvn test -D suiteFile=testng.xml . It needed space between -D and suiteFile

Why do you need the testng.xml file? Why not using JUnit Jupiter and just run the required test also upgrade your plugin version ... Afterwards you can run mvn -Dtest=TestClassXYZ test? Also for aspectj there should be existing a plugin which should handle the issues...
